# Tikz horizontal alignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins, marginpar

I have a prepared page margin but i require alignment three Tikz graphics horizontally, the three graphics width is more what `\textwidth` but minor what `\textwidth` + marginpar.

[image]

How i can position three graphic in this place without modify margins?
[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
%\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper
,inner=.75in
,top=.5in
,bottom=.5in
,includeheadfoot
,textwidth=5in
,marginparwidth=2in
,marginparsep=0.25in
,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepgfmodule{shapes}
\usepgfmodule{plot}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
 \usetikzlibrary{through}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
 \usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
 \usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[H]

\subfloat[]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
\useasboundingbox(-2.5,-2) rectangle (7,8.5);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (xyz cs:x=6);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (xyz cs:y=6);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (xyz cs:z=4);

\node[right=3pt,inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (6,0,0) (x) {$x$};
\node[above=3pt,inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (0,6,0) (y) {$y$};
\node[below=3pt,inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (0,0,4) (z) {$z$};


\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (1,2) (a) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (2,3.5) (b) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (2.5,5) (c) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (3.5,4.5) (d) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (4,2.5) (e) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (3,1) (f) {};

\shadedraw[inner color=brown!10,outer color=brown!80,draw=brown!80]
 plot [smooth cycle, tension=.8] coordinates { (a) (b) (c) (d) (e) (f)};

\node[inner sep=1pt, outer sep=1pt] (pa) at (3,2)  {};
\shade[ball color=green] (pa) circle (.1cm);
\node[inner sep=1pt, outer sep=1pt] (pb) at (2.8,4.5)  {};
\shade[ball color=green] (pb) circle (.1cm);
\node[right]  at (pa)  {$A$};
\node[right]  at (pb)  {$B$};

\draw[arrows={-latex},color=cyan,ultra thick] (0,0,0) -- node[color=cyan, midway=pt, left=5pt]{$r_{B}$} (pb);
\draw[arrows={-latex},color=cyan,ultra thick]  (0,0,0) -- node[color=cyan, midway, left=-25]{$r_{A}$} (pa);
\draw[arrows={-latex},color=cyan!70,ultra thick] (pa) -- node[color=cyan!70, midway, left=-30]{$r_{B/A}$} (pb);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subfloat[]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
%\useasboundingbox (-2.5,-2) rectangle (7,8.5);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (xyz cs:x=6);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (xyz cs:y=6);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (xyz cs:z=4);

\node[right=3pt,inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (6,0,0) (x) {$x$};
\node[above=3pt,inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (0,6,0) (y) {$y$};
\node[below=3pt,inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (0,0,4) (z) {$z$};


\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (1,2) (a) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (2,3.5) (b) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (2.5,5) (c) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (3.5,4.5) (d) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (4,2.5) (e) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (3,1) (f) {};

\shadedraw[inner color=brown!10,outer color=brown!80,draw=brown!80]
 plot [smooth cycle, tension=.8] coordinates { (a) (b) (c) (d) (e) (f)};

%\draw plot [smooth , tension=.8,color=cyan,ultra thick] coordinates { (1,1.5) (pa) (5,3)};
\draw[cyan,ultra thick] plot [smooth , tension=.8] coordinates { (1,2) (pa) (5.2,3.2)};
\draw[cyan,ultra thick] plot [smooth , tension=.8] coordinates { (1,4.5) (pb) (5,5.7)};

\node[inner sep=1pt, outer sep=1pt] (pa) at (3,2)  {};
\shade[ball color=green] (pa) circle (.1cm);
\node[inner sep=1pt, outer sep=1pt] (pb) at (2.8,4.5)  {};
\shade[ball color=green] (pb) circle (.1cm);
\node[above]  at (pa)  {$A$};
\node[above]  at (pb)  {$B$};


\draw[arrows={-latex},color=green!80!red!80!blue!80,ultra thick] (pb) -- node[color=green!80!blue!80!red!80, midway, below]{$V$} (5,5);

\draw[arrows={-latex},color=green!80!blue!80!red!80,ultra thick] (pa) -- node[color=green!80!blue!80!red!80, midway, below]{$V$} (5.2,2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\subfloat[]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
%\useasboundingbox (-2.5,-2) rectangle (7,8.5);

\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (xyz cs:x=6);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (xyz cs:y=6);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (xyz cs:z=4);

\node[right=3pt,inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (6,0,0) (x) {$x$};
\node[above=3pt,inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (0,6,0) (y) {$y$};
\node[below=3pt,inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (0,0,4) (z) {$z$};


\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (1,2) (a) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (2,3.5) (b) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (2.5,5) (c) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (3.5,4.5) (d) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (4,2.5) (e) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (3,1) (f) {};

\shadedraw[inner color=brown!10,outer color=brown!80,draw=brown!80]
 plot [smooth cycle, tension=.8] coordinates { (a) (b) (c) (d) (e) (f)};

%\draw plot [smooth , tension=.8,color=cyan,ultra thick] coordinates { (1,1.5) (pa) (5,3)};
\draw[cyan,ultra thick] plot [smooth , tension=.8] coordinates { (1,2) (pa) (5.2,3.2)};
\draw[cyan,ultra thick] plot [smooth , tension=.8] coordinates { (1,4.5) (pb) (5,5.7)};

\node[inner sep=1pt, outer sep=1pt] (pa) at (3,2)  {};
\shade[ball color=green] (pa) circle (.1cm);
\node[inner sep=1pt, outer sep=1pt] (pb) at (2.8,4.5)  {};
\shade[ball color=green] (pb) circle (.1cm);
\node[above]  at (pa)  {$A$};
\node[above]  at (pb)  {$B$};


\draw[arrows={-latex},color=red!80,ultra thick] (pb) -- node[color=red!80, near end, below]{$a$} (1,5.5);

\draw[arrows={-latex},color=red!80,ultra thick] (pa) -- node[color=red!80, near end, below]{$a$} (1.7,3);

\end{tikzpicture}
}

%\caption{dasdasdasd}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish that by removing the spurious spaces:

[image]

### Notes:

- As per @TorbjørnT.'s suggestion I added used [the `changepage` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/changepage) to eliminate the `Overfull \hbox` message.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
%\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper
,inner=.75in
,top=.5in
,bottom=.5in
,includeheadfoot
,textwidth=5in
,marginparwidth=2in
,marginparsep=0.25in
,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{changepage}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{pgf}
%\usepackage{pgffor}                        %% These are not necessary for this MWE
%\usepgfmodule{shapes}
%\usepgfmodule{plot}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
%\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
% \usetikzlibrary{through}
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
% \usepackage{epsfig}
%\usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
% \usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{adjustwidth}{0pt}{-83pt}
\subfloat[]{%      <---- Added %
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
\useasboundingbox(-2.5,-2) rectangle (7,8.5);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (xyz cs:x=6);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (xyz cs:y=6);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (xyz cs:z=4);

\node[right=3pt,inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (6,0,0) (x) {$x$};
\node[above=3pt,inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (0,6,0) (y) {$y$};
\node[below=3pt,inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (0,0,4) (z) {$z$};


\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (1,2) (a) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (2,3.5) (b) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (2.5,5) (c) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (3.5,4.5) (d) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (4,2.5) (e) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (3,1) (f) {};

\shadedraw[inner color=brown!10,outer color=brown!80,draw=brown!80]
 plot [smooth cycle, tension=.8] coordinates { (a) (b) (c) (d) (e) (f)};

\node[inner sep=1pt, outer sep=1pt] (pa) at (3,2)  {};
\shade[ball color=green] (pa) circle (.1cm);
\node[inner sep=1pt, outer sep=1pt] (pb) at (2.8,4.5)  {};
\shade[ball color=green] (pb) circle (.1cm);
\node[right]  at (pa)  {$A$};
\node[right]  at (pb)  {$B$};

\draw[arrows={-latex},color=cyan,ultra thick] (0,0,0) -- node[color=cyan, midway=pt, left=5pt]{$r_{B}$} (pb);
\draw[arrows={-latex},color=cyan,ultra thick]  (0,0,0) -- node[color=cyan, midway, left=-25]{$r_{A}$} (pa);
\draw[arrows={-latex},color=cyan!70,ultra thick] (pa) -- node[color=cyan!70, midway, left=-30]{$r_{B/A}$} (pb);
\end{tikzpicture}%       <---- Added %
}%       <---- Added %
\subfloat[]{%       <---- Added %
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
%\useasboundingbox (-2.5,-2) rectangle (7,8.5);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (xyz cs:x=6);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (xyz cs:y=6);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (xyz cs:z=4);

\node[right=3pt,inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (6,0,0) (x) {$x$};
\node[above=3pt,inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (0,6,0) (y) {$y$};
\node[below=3pt,inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (0,0,4) (z) {$z$};


\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (1,2) (a) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (2,3.5) (b) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (2.5,5) (c) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (3.5,4.5) (d) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (4,2.5) (e) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (3,1) (f) {};

\shadedraw[inner color=brown!10,outer color=brown!80,draw=brown!80]
 plot [smooth cycle, tension=.8] coordinates { (a) (b) (c) (d) (e) (f)};

%\draw plot [smooth , tension=.8,color=cyan,ultra thick] coordinates { (1,1.5) (pa) (5,3)};
\draw[cyan,ultra thick] plot [smooth , tension=.8] coordinates { (1,2) (pa) (5.2,3.2)};
\draw[cyan,ultra thick] plot [smooth , tension=.8] coordinates { (1,4.5) (pb) (5,5.7)};

\node[inner sep=1pt, outer sep=1pt] (pa) at (3,2)  {};
\shade[ball color=green] (pa) circle (.1cm);
\node[inner sep=1pt, outer sep=1pt] (pb) at (2.8,4.5)  {};
\shade[ball color=green] (pb) circle (.1cm);
\node[above]  at (pa)  {$A$};
\node[above]  at (pb)  {$B$};


\draw[arrows={-latex},color=green!80!red!80!blue!80,ultra thick] (pb) -- node[color=green!80!blue!80!red!80, midway, below]{$V$} (5,5);

\draw[arrows={-latex},color=green!80!blue!80!red!80,ultra thick] (pa) -- node[color=green!80!blue!80!red!80, midway, below]{$V$} (5.2,2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}%       <---- Added %
}%       <---- Added %
%       <---- Added %
\subfloat[]{%       <---- Added %
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
%\useasboundingbox (-2.5,-2) rectangle (7,8.5);

\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (xyz cs:x=6);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (xyz cs:y=6);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (xyz cs:z=4);

\node[right=3pt,inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (6,0,0) (x) {$x$};
\node[above=3pt,inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (0,6,0) (y) {$y$};
\node[below=3pt,inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (0,0,4) (z) {$z$};


\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (1,2) (a) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (2,3.5) (b) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (2.5,5) (c) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (3.5,4.5) (d) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (4,2.5) (e) {};
\node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (3,1) (f) {};

\shadedraw[inner color=brown!10,outer color=brown!80,draw=brown!80]
 plot [smooth cycle, tension=.8] coordinates { (a) (b) (c) (d) (e) (f)};

%\draw plot [smooth , tension=.8,color=cyan,ultra thick] coordinates { (1,1.5) (pa) (5,3)};
\draw[cyan,ultra thick] plot [smooth , tension=.8] coordinates { (1,2) (pa) (5.2,3.2)};
\draw[cyan,ultra thick] plot [smooth , tension=.8] coordinates { (1,4.5) (pb) (5,5.7)};

\node[inner sep=1pt, outer sep=1pt] (pa) at (3,2)  {};
\shade[ball color=green] (pa) circle (.1cm);
\node[inner sep=1pt, outer sep=1pt] (pb) at (2.8,4.5)  {};
\shade[ball color=green] (pb) circle (.1cm);
\node[above]  at (pa)  {$A$};
\node[above]  at (pb)  {$B$};


\draw[arrows={-latex},color=red!80,ultra thick] (pb) -- node[color=red!80, near end, below]{$a$} (1,5.5);

\draw[arrows={-latex},color=red!80,ultra thick] (pa) -- node[color=red!80, near end, below]{$a$} (1.7,3);

\end{tikzpicture}%       <---- Added %
}%       <---- Added %
%\caption{dasdasdasd}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does of course produce an `overfull hbox` warning. You could add the `changepage` package and use `\begin{adjustwidth}{0pt}{-83pt} <tikzpictures> \end{adjustwidth}` to remove that.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Thanks. Have incorporated your suggestion.